# Safari on iPhone: CSS Positioning off by 1px

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari, mobile-safari

Safari on the iPhone renders my {position: relative; top: 80px;} div 1px too low (all other browsers work fine) - is there any way to fix this via conditional css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin by this [Comprehensive List of Browser-Specific CSS Hacks](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/) (and comprehensive it is!)

```
/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #veintiseis { color: red  }
}
```